# EAP-PWD with FreeRADIUS 3.0.15 and Android phone

Tags: wifi, android-wifi, freeradius, radius

I installed FreeRADIUS-3.0.15 in Ubuntu-16.04.2, and set the EAP-PWD configurations (files: eap, users).

**With EAP-PWD,
I could get SUCCESS by eapol_test tool, but I could NOT get my Android phone (v5.1.1 & 7.1.2) passed the authentication processes.**
　With the same settings, I could get my Android phone passed the authentication through TTLS and PEAP.

I've read the post,
https://serverfault.com/questions/683897/eap-pwd-with-freeradius-3/683923#683923.
But, it doesn't appear if the EAP-PWD could finally work in Android phones with FreeRADIUS server.

Are there any configurations I missed ?
Does EAP-PWD need some specific devices (e.g. AP, Switch-Controller, etc..) to work with ?

The EAP-PWD settings in the file "eap" :

```
pwd {
    group = 19
    server_id = theserver@example.com
    fragment_size = 1020
    virtual_server = "inner-tunnel"
}
```

The fail RADIUS server logs using my Android phone :

```
Ready to process requests
(0) Received Access-Request Id 19 from 192.168.1.1:65514 to 192.168.1.48:1812 length 113
(0)   User-Name = "steve"
(0)   NAS-Port-Type = Wireless-802.11
(0)   Called-Station-Id = "00-0A-79-98-19-1F"
(0)   Calling-Station-Id = "90-B6-86-8E-8E-F2"
(0)   NAS-IP-Address = 192.168.1.1
(0)   Framed-MTU = 1400
(0)   EAP-Message = 0x0201000a017374657665
(0)   Message-Authenticator = 0xfc142f419a003e1f32c49845e2b47148
(0) # Executing section authorize from file /usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(0)   authorize {
(0)     policy filter_username {
(0)       if (&User-Name) {
(0)       if (&User-Name)  -> TRUE
(0)       if (&User-Name)  {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ / /) {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ / /)  -> FALSE
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ ) {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ )  -> FALSE
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ ) {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ )  -> FALSE
(0)         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))  {
(0)         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))   -> FALSE
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)  {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)   -> FALSE
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)  {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)   -> FALSE
(0)       } # if (&User-Name)  = notfound
(0)     } # policy filter_username = notfound
(0)     [preprocess] = ok
(0)     [chap] = noop
(0)     [mschap] = noop
(0)     [digest] = noop
(0) suffix: Checking for suffix after "@"
(0) suffix: No '@' in User-Name = "steve", looking up realm NULL
(0) suffix: No such realm "NULL"
(0)     [suffix] = noop
(0) eap: Peer sent EAP Response (code 2) ID 1 length 10
(0) eap: EAP-Identity reply, returning 'ok' so we can short-circuit the rest of authorize
(0)     [eap] = ok
(0)   } # authorize = ok
(0) Found Auth-Type = eap
(0) # Executing group from file /usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(0)   authenticate {
(0) eap: Peer sent packet with method EAP Identity (1)
(0) eap: Calling submodule eap_md5 to process data
(0) eap_md5: Issuing MD5 Challenge
(0) eap: Sending EAP Request (code 1) ID 2 length 22
(0) eap: EAP session adding &reply:State = 0x0920d2120922d68e
(0)     [eap] = handled
(0)   } # authenticate = handled
(0) Using Post-Auth-Type Challenge
(0) # Executing group from file /usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(0)   Challenge { ... } # empty sub-section is ignored
(0) Sent Access-Challenge Id 19 from 192.168.1.48:1812 to 192.168.1.1:65514 length 0
(0)   EAP-Message = 0x01020016041003e295427e4313c871b5357ea94cb0cd
(0)   Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
(0)   State = 0x0920d2120922d68e7c074922ee6197b2
(0) Finished request
Waking up in 4.9 seconds.
(1) Received Access-Request Id 20 from 192.168.1.1:65515 to 192.168.1.48:1812 length 127
(1)   User-Name = "steve"
(1)   NAS-Port-Type = Wireless-802.11
(1)   Called-Station-Id = "00-0A-79-98-19-1F"
(1)   Calling-Station-Id = "90-B6-86-8E-8E-F2"
(1)   NAS-IP-Address = 192.168.1.1
(1)   Framed-MTU = 1400
(1)   State = 0x0920d2120922d68e7c074922ee6197b2
(1)   EAP-Message = 0x020200060334
(1)   Message-Authenticator = 0x957e6bdb393fe8c0829f734afa134684
(1) session-state: No cached attributes
(1) # Executing section authorize from file /usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(1)   authorize {
(1)     policy filter_username {
(1)       if (&User-Name) {
(1)       if (&User-Name)  -> TRUE
(1)       if (&User-Name)  {
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ / /) {
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ / /)  -> FALSE
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ ) {
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ )  -> FALSE
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ ) {
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ )  -> FALSE
(1)         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))  {
(1)         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))   -> FALSE
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)  {
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)   -> FALSE
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)  {
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)   -> FALSE
(1)       } # if (&User-Name)  = notfound
(1)     } # policy filter_username = notfound
(1)     [preprocess] = ok
(1)     [chap] = noop
(1)     [mschap] = noop
(1)     [digest] = noop
(1) suffix: Checking for suffix after "@"
(1) suffix: No '@' in User-Name = "steve", looking up realm NULL
(1) suffix: No such realm "NULL"
(1)     [suffix] = noop
(1) eap: Peer sent EAP Response (code 2) ID 2 length 6
(1) eap: No EAP Start, assuming it's an on-going EAP conversation
(1)     [eap] = updated
(1) files: users: Matched entry steve at line 73
(1)     [files] = ok
(1)     [expiration] = noop
(1)     [logintime] = noop
(1) pap: WARNING: Auth-Type already set.  Not setting to PAP
(1)     [pap] = noop
(1)   } # authorize = updated
(1) Found Auth-Type = eap
(1) # Executing group from file /usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(1)   authenticate {
(1) eap: Expiring EAP session with state 0x0920d2120922d68e
(1) eap: Finished EAP session with state 0x0920d2120922d68e
(1) eap: Previous EAP request found for state 0x0920d2120922d68e, released from the list
(1) eap: Peer sent packet with method EAP NAK (3)
(1) eap: Found mutually acceptable type PWD (52)
(1) eap: Calling submodule eap_pwd to process data
(1) eap: Sending EAP Request (code 1) ID 3 length 36
(1) eap: EAP session adding &reply:State = 0x0920d2120823e68e
(1)     [eap] = handled
(1)   } # authenticate = handled
(1) Using Post-Auth-Type Challenge
(1) # Executing group from file /usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(1)   Challenge { ... } # empty sub-section is ignored
(1) Sent Access-Challenge Id 20 from 192.168.1.48:1812 to 192.168.1.1:65515 length 0
(1)   EAP-Message = 0x010300243401001301015bd0471300746865736572766572406578616d706c652e636f6d
(1)   Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
(1)   State = 0x0920d2120823e68e7c074922ee6197b2
(1) Finished request
Waking up in 4.9 seconds.
(0) Cleaning up request packet ID 19 with timestamp +59
(1) Cleaning up request packet ID 20 with timestamp +59
Ready to process requests
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem after a long test.

Within the same system settings and environments, just needed to replace the AP to another one (I thought that the problem was caused because some APs (or their firmwares) did not support the function of EAP-PWD), and the problem could be solved.